# open new windows in javascript

Tags: javascript

hi how to use javascriptscript to open a new window and then closing the current window..

currently, i can only open a new window, however my current window is still left open.

Code:

```
function newfunction()
        {
            window.open("index.html", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0");
        }
```

Comment: by the way "windows" tag has different meaning, I have removed it from this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening a new window and closing the old one sounds very much like changing the current page to me. Use `location.href = 'newurl'`.

And if you want to change its size and so on, that can also be done.

```
window.innerWidth = 300;
window.innerHeight = 300;
location.href = 'newurl';
```

Answer (score 0):

use like you said window.open and then in the main window window.close(). But if you use like this, the browser will ask you "This website wants to close this window blabla".

Answer (score 0):

add  `window.opener.close();`

```
 function newfunction()
            {
                window.open("index.html", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0"); 
                window.opener.close();

            }
```

or add this on the `index.html` file whenever a new window open it will close the parent window

```
<body onload="window.opener.close()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
function newfunction()
{
   window.open("index.html", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0");
   window.close();
}
```

This will work only if the current window was opened via script as well, otherwise IE show warning dialog and other browsers might simply ignore it.